# What dependencies does bundler download for Redmine 2.5.0?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, dependencies, redmine

The linux machine that I'm installing Redmine on, does not have internet access, so I can't simply use bundler to install dependencies. I've so far been downloading gems + dependencies from a windows machine that does not have bundler (and can't install it).

I'm trying to locate a list of the gems needed by Redmine 2.5.0 that bundler normally installs so that I can do it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is our gemlock file from the Bitnami Redmine 2.5.0 stack.

GEM

remote: https://rubygems.org/

specs:

actionmailer (3.2.17)

actionpack (= 3.2.17)

mail (~> 2.5.4)

actionpack (3.2.17)

activemodel (= 3.2.17)

activesupport (= 3.2.17)

builder (~> 3.0.0)

erubis (~> 2.7.0)

journey (~> 1.0.4)

rack (~> 1.4.5)

rack-cache (~> 1.2)

rack-test (~> 0.6.1)

sprockets (~> 2.2.1)

activemodel (3.2.17)

activesupport (= 3.2.17)

builder (~> 3.0.0)

activerecord (3.2.17)

activemodel (= 3.2.17)

activesupport (= 3.2.17)

arel (~> 3.0.2)

tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)

activeresource (3.2.17)

activemodel (= 3.2.17)

activesupport (= 3.2.17)

activesupport (3.2.17)

i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.4)

multi_json (~> 1.0)

arel (3.0.3)

awesome_nested_set (2.1.6)

activerecord (>= 3.0.0)

builder (3.0.0)

capybara (2.1.0)

mime-types (>= 1.16)

nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)

rack (>= 1.0.0)

rack-test (>= 0.5.4)

xpath (~> 2.0)

childprocess (0.3.6)

ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.6)

coderay (1.1.0)

erubis (2.7.0)

fastercsv (1.5.4)

ffi (1.9.3)

hike (1.2.3)

i18n (0.6.9)

journey (1.0.4)

jquery-rails (2.0.3)

railties (>= 3.1.0, < 5.0)

thor (~> 0.14)

json (1.8.1)

mail (2.5.4)

mime-types (~> 1.16)

treetop (~> 1.4.8)

metaclass (0.0.1)

mime-types (1.25.1)

mini_portile (0.5.2)

mocha (0.14.0)

metaclass (~> 0.0.1)

multi_json (1.8.4)

mysql2 (0.3.13)

net-ldap (0.3.1)

nokogiri (1.6.1)

mini_portile (~> 0.5.0)

polyglot (0.3.4)

rack (1.4.5)

rack-cache (1.2)

rack (>= 0.4)

rack-openid (1.3.1)

rack (>= 1.1.0)

ruby-openid (>= 2.1.8)

rack-ssl (1.3.3)

rack

rack-test (0.6.2)

rack (>= 1.0)

rails (3.2.17)

actionmailer (= 3.2.17)

actionpack (= 3.2.17)

activerecord (= 3.2.17)

activeresource (= 3.2.17)

activesupport (= 3.2.17)

bundler (~> 1.0)

railties (= 3.2.17)

railties (3.2.17)

actionpack (= 3.2.17)

activesupport (= 3.2.17)

rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)

rake (>= 0.8.7)

rdoc (~> 3.4)

thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)

rake (10.1.1)

rdoc (3.12.2)

json (~> 1.4)

redcarpet (2.3.0)

rmagick (2.13.2)

ruby-openid (2.3.0)

rubyzip (1.1.0)

selenium-webdriver (2.35.0)

childprocess (>= 0.2.5)

multi_json (~> 1.0)

rubyzip

websocket (~> 1.0.4)

sprockets (2.2.2)

hike (~> 1.2)

multi_json (~> 1.0)

rack (~> 1.0)

tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)

thor (0.18.1)

tilt (1.4.1)

treetop (1.4.15)

polyglot

polyglot (>= 0.3.1)

tzinfo (0.3.38)

websocket (1.0.6)

xpath (2.0.0)

nokogiri (~> 1.3)

yard (0.8.1)

PLATFORMS

ruby

DEPENDENCIES

activerecord-jdbc-adapter (~> 1.3.2)

activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter

awesome_nested_set (= 2.1.6)

builder (= 3.0.0)

capybara (~> 2.1.0)

coderay (~> 1.1.0)

fastercsv (~> 1.5.0)

jquery-rails (~> 2.0.2)

mime-types

mocha (>= 0.14)

mysql2 (= 0.3.13)

net-ldap (~> 0.3.1)

rack-openid

rails (= 3.2.17)

rdoc (>= 2.4.2)

redcarpet (~> 2.3.0)

rmagick (>= 2.0.0)

ruby-openid (~> 2.3.0)

selenium-webdriver

yard